# MySQL - Remove substring from an entry that contains some host

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove every link that have "host1"

I have a table that have a column with data like this:

Note: the host addresses are completely different

```
["http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro33244","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro14646","http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro122278"]
["http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro13244","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro14556","http:\/\/host6\/pasta\/ficheiro14678"]
["http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro155244","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro14646","http:\/\/host5\/pasta\/ficheiro14678","http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro14678"]
["http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro66244","http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro146446","http:\/\/host4\/pasta\/ficheiro1465678"]
["http:\/\/host5\/pasta\/ficheiro13244","http:\/\/host4\/pasta\/ficheiro143346","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro13338"]
["http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro13774","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro1463336","http:\/\/host4\/pasta\/ficheiro14678"]
["http:\/\/host5\/pasta\/ficheiro88844","http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro1463336","http:\/\/host4\/pasta\/ficheiro1448","http:\/\/host5\/pasta\/ficheiro14678"]
["http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro99244","http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro1433346","http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro16678"]
["http:\/\/host1\/pasta\/ficheiro188244","http:\/\/host3\/pasta\/ficheiro14646","http:\/\/host2\/pasta\/ficheiro17778"]
```

Comment: Should chost1 or host11 be removed too?

Comment: the host addresses are completely different, there will be no such problem